# Can the Origen compiler run in concatenation mode?

Tags: origen-sdk

I am using the [Origen compiler](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/compiler/running/) quite a bit and wonder if there is a concatenation mode?  Concatenation mode would be where the compiler checks for an existing fle and if it exists would append to the file rather than overwrite it.

thx

Comment: What does concatenation mode mean?

Comment: @Ginty I edited the original question to provide more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't have that currently.